# What makes the different performances between numpy.sum and numpy.cumsum?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

If my understanding is correct, both `np.sum` and `np.cumsum` will take `O(n)` time. However, when I do both operations to the same matrix sequentially (on different axis), it seems the sequence of `np.sum` and `np.cumsum` makes the overall performance quite different, though the result is the same as expected.

If I do the `np.cumsum` along column direction (`axis=1`) for each row first, and then do `np.sum` for all the rows (`axis=0`), it will take longer time.

If I do the `np.sum` along rows (`axis=0`) first, then do `np.cumsum` for the one dimension array, it will take shorter time.

My hypothesis is that the `np.cumsum` will take more time on the data allocation/manipulation since it will yield more data than `np.sum`, so it will take longer time if there are more operations of `np.cumsum`.

Here is my testing code and result

```
import numpy as np
import time

b = np.zeros((1000, 1000))
for i in range(1000):
    b[i] = np.array(range(1000))

time_start = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    c = np.cumsum(b, axis=1)
    d = np.sum(c, axis=0)
time_end = time.time()
print(f"np.sum(np.cumsum(...)) time: {time_end - time_start}")


time_start = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    c = np.cumsum(np.sum(b, axis=0))
time_end = time.time()
print(f"np.cumsum(np.sum(...)) time: {time_end - time_start}")
```

The result is

```
np.sum(np.cumsum(...)) time: 3.6612446308135986
np.cumsum(np.sum(...)) time: 0.38796162605285645
```

Comment: In your first loop, `c` has shape `(1000, 1000)`, the same as `b`, so you are computing 1 million cumulative sums and then the sum of 1000 vectors of length 1000. In your second loop, you compute the 1000 sums first, and then compute only 1000 cumulative sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your alternatives applied to a small array.

```
In [45]: b = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
In [46]: b
Out[46]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

sum(cumsum(b)):

```
In [47]: np.cumsum(b, axis=1)         # same shape as b
Out[47]: 
array([[  0,   1,   3,   6,  10,  15],
       [  6,  13,  21,  30,  40,  51],
       [ 12,  25,  39,  54,  70,  87],
       [ 18,  37,  57,  78, 100, 123]])
In [48]: np.sum(_, axis=0)
Out[48]: array([ 36,  76, 120, 168, 220, 276])
```

sum first:

```
In [49]: np.sum(b, axis=0)            # much reduced array
Out[49]: array([36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56])
In [50]: np.cumsum(_)
Out[50]: array([ 36,  76, 120, 168, 220, 276])
```

While the first step operates on the same number of elements, the whole `b`, the second step works with a much reduced array when `sum` is done first.

Actually for this small sample the time differences are minor:

```
In [57]: timeit np.sum(np.cumsum(b,axis=1), axis=0)
17.8 µs ± 29.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [58]: timeit np.cumsum(np.sum(b, axis=0))
16.1 µs ± 30.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But for a bigger array, the time savings due to the reduction becomes significant:

```
In [59]: b = np.random.randint(0,1000,(1000,1000))
In [60]: timeit np.sum(np.cumsum(b,axis=1), axis=0)
5.11 ms ± 9.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [61]: timeit np.cumsum(np.sum(b, axis=0))
1.64 ms ± 649 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Looking at the first step by itself:

```
In [62]: timeit np.cumsum(b,axis=1)
3.73 ms ± 12.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [63]: timeit np.sum(b, axis=0)
1.62 ms ± 1.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

`cumsum`, because it returns a full `b.shape` array is slower.

`O(n)` tells us something about how an operation scales, such as when operating on small arrays versus big ones.  But it can't be used to compare one operation to another.  In addition with `numpy`, the core calculations are done rapidly in compiled code, but memory management and other setup issues may swamp that core time.

### edit

`np.sum` is essentially `np.add.reduce`:

```
In [79]: timeit np.add.reduce(b,axis=0)
1.59 ms ± 4.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [80]: timeit np.sum(b,axis=0)
1.64 ms ± 5.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

And `np.cumsum` is `np.add.accumulate`:

```
In [81]: timeit np.cumsum(b,axis=0)
10.2 ms ± 357 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [82]: timeit np.add.accumulate(b,axis=0)
10 ms ± 14.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

> If my understanding is correct, both np.sum and np.cumsum will take O(n) time.

Correct (assuming the input is the same)!

> it seems the sequence of np.sum and np.cumsum makes the overall performance quite different

**`np.cumsum` is more expensive than `np.sum`** on the *same input* since `np.cumsum` needs to allocate and write an output array (which can be pretty big). Moreover, assuming floating-point operations are associative, the implementation of `np.sum` can be easily optimized while it is quite hard to optimize `np.cumsum`.

> My hypothesis is that the np.cumsum will take more time on the data allocation/manipulation since it will yield more data than np.sum, so it will take longer time if there are more operations of np.cumsum.

The thing is that the first implementation have much more work to do than the second. This is mainly why it is slower, especially because of the memory reads/writes. Indeed, `np.cumsum` produces a big 2D array in the first implementation that must be computed by `np.sum`. **Writing and reading this temporary array is expensive**. In the example, the first implementation require to move 14.9 GiB from/to the memory hierarchy (likely in RAM) just for the temporary array. Note that building a temporary array also make the computation less **cache-friendly** as it requires more space and thus `b` and `c` may not both fit in the cache any more (`b` and `c` takes 8 MiB each on my machine and my CPU have a L3 cache of 9 MiB which mean that not both can fit in the cache) as opposed to the second implementation. The throughput of the RAM is often much smaller than the one of the CPU caches.

Note that the second implementation also produces temporary arrays. This version should allocate as much temporary arrays as the first one. However, the second implementation produces temporary arrays that are *1000 time smaller*! Thus, the call to `np.cumsum` is much faster in this version. On my machine, `b` is mostly stored in the fast L3 cache and temporary arrays in the very fast L1 cache.